# Código para gerar a hash da senha do usuário no Oracle 10G com C#?

Tags: c#, criptografia, hash, oracle10g

estou precisando autenticar usuários em uma aplicação WEB no banco de dados do Oracle 10g, porém as credenciais são nativas do banco por rodar já uma aplicação Oracle Forms, e gostaríamos de manter a mesma senha em ambos os sistema (Single Sign-On).

Para isso preciso criptografar via C#, a senha que o usuário insere no formulário WEB para poder fazer a autenticação (validação se a HASH gerada for igual a salva no banco!).

Encontrei este código em PHP, porém até tentei converter mais sem sucesso, já que PHP não é o meu forte:

```
<?php
function oracle($un, $pw)
{
    $pt  = strtoupper($un . $pw);
    $pt .= str_repeat("\0", 3 - ((strlen($pt) - 1) & 3));
    $end = strlen($pt);
    $pt .= $pt;
    for ($a = 0; $a < $end; $a++)
    {
        $pt[2 * $a] = "\0";
        $pt[2 * $a + 1] = $pt[$a + $end];
    }
    $ct = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, hex2bin('0123456789ABCDEF'), $pt, 'cbc', "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
    $ct = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, substr($ct, -8), $pt, 'cbc', "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
    return bin2hex(substr($ct, -8));
}
?>
```

E realmente funciona pois testei com os seguintes dados:

Usuário: rota

Senha: teste

Hash Gerada: 89574FB579B04A40 (igual ao que está no banco de dados)

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Comment: Sua pergunta, é sobre PHP ou C#?

Comment: "Para isso preciso criptografar via C#" .... tenho um código PHP que faz o que preciso ... porém precisaria em C# !

Comment: A maneira correta de integrar uma camada Oracle SSO e uma aplicação .NET é utilizando o serviço nativo do Application Server (10gAS ou superior). Duplicação de *hashes* fragilizará a segurança dos dois sistemas.

Comment: @OnoSendai não duplicaremos HASHes, apenas usarei para authenticar a HASH já gerada pelo Oracle... só para authenticar via WEB! Nada além...  Caso mude a senha pelo sistema do banco, a HASH a ser autenticada pela web será a nova gerada pelo sistema oracle! Agradeço a sua sugestão... mas não consegui ver a fragilização em ambos os sistemas fazendo desta forma, poderia ser mais explícito ?

Comment: @MaurícioJúnior Assuma um agente malicioso que não conhece o algoritmo utilizado para gerar o *hash*. Sua aplicação é um cliente C# que roda localmente. De posse do *assembly*, este agente descompila seu programa (utilizando uma ferramente como o DotPeek.) Ele agora conhece o algoritmo de geração do *hash*; Não só o seu programa cliente foi comprometido, mas também o serviço remoto.

Comment: @OnoSendai entendi amigo... Obrigado pela observação...

Comment: Em algumas linguagens há uma sigla md5 que se coloca antes da variável da senha

Answer (score 1):

Segue o código PHP convertido para C#.

```
    public static string HashOracle(string usuario, string senha)
    {
        senha = (usuario + senha).ToUpper();
        senha = senha + "".PadLeft(3 - ((senha.Length - 1) & 3), '\0');
        var len = senha.Length;
        var array = (senha + senha).ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            array[i * 2] = '\0';
            array[i * 2 + 1] = array[i + len];
        }

        senha = new string(array);
        string hash = Crypt(senha, "0123456789ABCDEF", "0000000000000000");
        hash = Crypt(senha, hash.Substring(hash.Length - 16), "0000000000000000");
        hash = hash.Substring(hash.Length - 16);
        return hash.ToUpper();
    }

    public static string Crypt(string text, string hexKey, string hexIV)
    {
        byte[] key = Hex2bin(hexKey);
        byte[] iv = Hex2bin(hexIV);
        System.Security.Cryptography.DES algorithm = System.Security.Cryptography.DES.Create();
        algorithm.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
        algorithm.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.None;
        System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        byte[] inputbuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);
        return Bin2hex(outputBuffer);
    }

    public static byte[] Hex2bin(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }

    public static string Bin2hex(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

Observações:

Usei o encoding UTF8 mas talvez seja necessário conferir qual o encoding que o Oracle usa nas senhas (senhas com acentos podem dar problema. No código que enviei previamente pra ti, usei ASCII).

Comment: Muito bom! Parabéns....